# How do you host Django's dev server on an external IP?

Tags: django, web-development-server

Basically, my internal IP is masked by an external IP of my internet service provider. So, my internal IP can only be accessed inside my intranet. I want to let users outside the intranet to access my Dev server as well which is hosted on 0.0.0.0:8000 on my system. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm assuming you have an purchased external IP address for your dev server correct? If not you can't do this.

Comment: what do you mean by `masked`? are you using a router? if so you should be able to set up port forwarding on port :8000 so your public ip ex 122.123.123.123:8000 will forward to your computer

Comment: Its actually my college has a masked IP. I haven't bought one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to go that far you can use **Reverse SSH Tunnel**:
open a free micro linux instance on Amazon's AWS and create a reverse SSH tunnel to redirect port 80 on the server to your machine.

This is a cool solution for testing purposes and low traffic usage...

You can read more about it here:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/setting-up-a-reverse-ssh-tunnel/5779944

Comment: This is awesome! The problem is that it requires the client computer to keep a SSH tunnel open. I'm hoping the localtunnel v2 beta issue is solved. Thanks a lot!
And I also found a question that explains reverse SSH tunnels in detail - http://superuser.com/questions/303400/forwarding-specific-ports-through-ssh-reverse-tunnels.

Answer (score 2):

Check out localtunnel on github, it does exactly what you're asking.

https://github.com/progrium/localtunnel

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is that localtunnel has some issue with the Django development server. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/localtunnel/Nubbroye27k

Comment: Ahh ok-- I've used the ruby gem localtunnel, and now saw that there was a python one and recommended that.  The ruby gem localtunnel does in fact work with the django dev server(I've used that one before)